# Why does HTML5 video not work in the new Windows version of Safari?

Tags: html, html5-video, safari

I've tested on several installations of Safari 5.1.7 for Windows and I can't seem to get HTML5 videos to play.

I've been testing with this:
[Basic HTML5 video test](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html)

It seems to work on Safari 5.1.7 for Mac and also earlier 5.0.x installations of Safari on Windows. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Managed to fix this. For anyone else encountering similar problems, note that Safari requires quicktime in order to play HTML5 video/audio. If you've upgrade to a later version of Safari and notice that HTML5 video/audio stops working, you may also need to upgrade to the latest version of quicktime.

Comment: How can they say that is native if it requires a plugin?

Comment: Apple has since discontinued Safari for Windows so this issue is probably irrelevant